# How can I use "Def " and "Return" code in python 3.0

Tags: python, syntax-error, python-idle

[image: Def, return]

```
>>> def square(x):
    return x*x
print (square(4))
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Hi, can you help me out about this programming problem ?
I used python 3.0 to write the code, but it seems like error . I have looked for the answer from several website  that can’t solve the problem. Even I copied others code to write , it still , the error showed up ..

Comment: In Python, the way you indent your lines matters. The way you copied your code snippet doesn't really reflect what's on your screenshot. So I assume you've messed up your indentation.

Comment: You have pasted more than one statement (`def `and `print`) at the `>>>`  prompt. IDLE doesn't accept that. Everything typed at the prompt must be a single statement or the beginning of one. Paste the function definition and the `print()` call in 2 separate steps.

Comment: If one enters the same 3 lines into standard interactive Python REPL, with the middle line indented, one gets the same error message.  So this is not about IDLE at all.  In 3.10+, IDLE's Shell keeps the code lines properly lined up, as in the REPL.  I may or may not backport the change to 3.9.

Answer (score 1):

So def works with similar formatting to if else's and for loops.
This means your code should look something like

```
def square(x):
  return x*x
print(square(4)
```

Although you could cut out the function and just have

```
print(x^2)
```

Comment: _similar formatting_, you could simply say that function definition are supposed to indented.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my example you can examine it:

```
def cal(x, y):
    return x+y
print(f"10 + 10 = {cal(10, 10)}")
```

And How To Use Parameters:

```
def cal(x,y, operation=None):
    opt = ['+', '-', '*', '/']
    if not operation in opt:
        raise TypeError("No Operation To Use")
    elif operation == opt[0]:
        # +
        return x+y
    elif operation == opt[1]:
        # -
        return x-y
    elif operation == opt[2]:
        # *
        return x*y
    elif operation == opt[3]:
        # /
        return x/y
    else:
        print(f"Operation {operation} is unkown")
```

call it using `cal(10, 5, operation='+')` or `cal(10, 5, '+')`

also it's better to use `print("Hi")` instead of `print "Hi"` or `print ("Hi")` because print is not a syntax